# Remove items from list (.net 2.0)

Tags: list, .net-2.0

I would like to remove items from a list that fulfill certain conditions. I made an example what I came up with so far:

```
//remove 1´s and 3´s from list of ints

List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
ints.Add(1);
ints.Add(2);
ints.Add(3);

foreach (int i in ints)
{
    if(i == 1 || i == 3)
    indexes.Add(ints.IndexOf(i));
}

indexes.Reverse();

foreach (int index in indexes)
{
    ints.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

I am curious if the solution can be optimized? I cannot use System.Linq, I have only found the System.Data.Linq namespace as reference (Visual Studio 2005)

**UPDATE**

I better had posted my real code. It is about deleting columns from a gridview

```
List<int> indexes = new List<int>();

foreach (Type type in types)
{
     foreach (DataControlField c in entriesGrid.Columns)
     {
          string header = c.HeaderText;
          if (header == type.Name)
          {
              indexes.Add(entriesGrid.Columns.IndexOf(c));
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: ...if a solution is good, you should certainly keep the question. That's the whole point of the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use `List<T>.RemoveAll()`?

```
ints.RemoveAll(IsOneOrThree); // Remove all 1's or 3's

private static bool IsOneOrThree(int i)
{
    return i == 1 || i == 3;
}
```

If it's not that simple (guessing it's really not, you could try):

```
for(int i= ints.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(ints[i] == 1 || ints[i] == 3)
        ints.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

This saves you the cost of another list and multiple iterations.

Comment: You are right, I just used ints as example, but thanks anyway

Comment: @Jan-Frederik Carl - Look at the second example using a single reverse loop to remove the items that match your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Try RemoveAll:

```
public bool MyPredicate(int i){
  return i == 3 || i == 5;
}

ints.RemoveAll(MyPredicate);
```

or if you have access to anonymous delegates:

```
ints.RemoveAll( (i) => i == 3 || i == 5 );
```

In addition, it is not usually a good idea to remove your question from SO, so that in the future people who might have the same question can read and learn from this.

Answer (score 0):

A more granular example for RemoveAll can be found below (links to .NET 2.0):

[List<T>.RemoveAll Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)